# Invalid syntax in a variable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code is below

```
i=0
a=0
Matrix[0]=0
Matrix = [1 for i in range(1000)]
while i<1000:
    i=i+1
    Matrix[i]=(1/1000)*((i*(1/1000))^2
    a=a+Matrix[i]
print (a)
```

When I try to run the program, Python highlight the first a in the 8th row and it says invalid syntax.
I can't figure out what is the problem with the code.

Much appreciated if you helped

Comment: Count the number of parentheses on the line above....

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses here: `((i*(1/1000))^2`

Comment: Also, `^2` should probably be `**2`. `^` is xor, `**` is power.

Comment: Also, don't use the same variable inside the list comprehension (`for i in range`) as outside of it, that's going to hurt (edit: or maybe not in Python 3?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected Code:

```
i=0
a=0
Matrix=[1 for i in range(1000)]
while i<1000:
  Matrix[i]=(1/1000)*((i*(1/1000)))**2
  a=a+Matrix[i]
  i=i+1
print (a)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer

Comment: Why downvote for my answer??

Comment: I did not downvoted your answer. Was very helpful and worked! I don't know what happened.

Comment: but you can accept it if you find it useful @AlexandrosMylonas

Comment: Thanks mate @AlexandrosMylonas

Comment: Ok, I did it I did not know this feature ;)